# How Should I Model this Relationship for a Document in RavenDB?

Tags: ravendb

I am working on my first serious project with RavenDB and would like to solicit suggestions. I currently have two concepts in my domain, Presenters and Presentations. Presenters can present many times and a Presentation has one Presenter currently. In a relational model I would have two tables, but am not sure how to select document schema.

I would like to be able to show up coming presentations with some minimal info about the presenter as well as have a presenters page that shows info about all of their presentations. 
What I have come up with is located here:

Presenter: https://github.com/ssdnug/Public-Site/blob/master/src/Web/Models/Presenter.cs

Presentation: https://github.com/ssdnug/Public-Site/blob/master/src/Web/Models/Presentation.cs

Anyone have suggestions on a better schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current model is optimized for ultimate performance as it denormalizes the references on both ends. Generally this is good, but it comes with the cost of having to do more work when the title changes on either side.

If you can live with slightly less performance (in most cases you definitely *can*) I'd rather go with the `.Include()` approach instead.

For a general overview about what options you have to address this relation-thing, take a look here at my post: http://daniellang.net/how-to-handle-relations-in-ravendb/

Comment: Hi Daniel - The link above no longer reaches that article. Is it still available?

Answer (score 3):

NotMyself,
You don't need the Presenter.Presentations property. You are very rarely, if ever, going to have to try to load the presentations from the presenter, and when you do, you'll want to make this with paging,sorting,etc.

De-normalizing the Presenter in the presentation is good. You won't need to update the presenter name ever.
For example, I used to go mainly as Ayende Rahien, now I go as Oren Eini. Old presentations don't need to change, though.